# How to compose functions that return Option[List] in Scala?

Tags: scala, monads

Suppose I have two functions to get orders and order items:

```
def getOrders(): Option[List[Int]] = ...
def getOrderItems(orderId: Int): Option[List[Int]] = ...
```

Note that both functions return `Option[List]` since each function may fail.

Now I would like to get `Option` of `List` of all order items as follows:

- return `Some[List]` if both functions return `Some` and
- `None` if any of them returns None.

I tried to compose these functions with `for` (see below) but it did not work.

```
val allOrderItems = for {
  orderIds   <- getOrders();
  orderId    <- orderIds;
  orderItems <- getOrderItems(orderId)
} yield orderItems
```

How can I build a function `getAllOrderItems():Option[List[Int]]` using functions `getOrders` and `getOrderItems` ?

Comment: What do you mean with "it did not work"? Did you get an error, or different results than what you expected? What did you expect and how does this differ from what it actually does?

Comment: The Option and the List monads are not compatible. You need to use monad transformers, or call toList on the Options (or breakOut with the proper type might also work).

Comment: @GáborBakos Thank you. `monad transformer` looks like an advanced topic. Besides, I would need `scalaz` for that. How would you suggest do that with `breakOut` ?

Comment: @Michael In that case would probably just call toList after getOrder(), like getOrder().toList. I am not sure breakOut can be used here, but that was designed for similar use cases. (Though in this case toList seems to be easier.)

Comment: @GáborBakos Thanks. `toList` looks really simple.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You really want to be able to turn the middle two layers of `Option[List[Option[List[Int]]]]` inside out, so that you can get the options and lists next to each other. This operation is called sequencing, and it's provided by Scalaz:

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._

val items: Option[List[Int]] =
  getOrders.flatMap(_.map(getOrderItems).sequence).map(_.flatten)
```

You could equivalently use `traverse`, which combines the `map` and `sequence` operations:

```
val items: Option[List[Int]] =
  getOrders.flatMap(_ traverse getOrderItems).map(_.flatten)
```

If you don't want to use Scalaz, you could write your own (less polymorphic) `sequence`:

```
def sequence[A](xs: List[Option[A]]) = xs.foldRight(Some(Nil): Option[List[A]]) {
  case (Some(h), Some(t)) => Some(h :: t)
  case _ => None
}
```

And then:

```
val items: Option[List[Int]] = getOrders.flatMap(
  orderIds => sequence(orderIds.map(getOrderItems))
).map(_.flatten)
```

The monad transformation solution is actually pretty straightforward as well (if you're willing to use Scalaz):

```
val items: Option[List[Int]] = (
  for {
    orderId <- ListT(getOrders)
    itemId  <- ListT(getOrderItems(orderId))
  } yield itemId
).underlying
```

The nice thing about this approach is that you don't have to think about where you need to flatten, sequence, etc.—the plain old monadic operations do exactly what you want.

Comment: Thank you ! I like `ListT` but I do not really understand how it works. In order to understand it I should define my own monad `OptionalList`, solve that "order" exercise with it and then generalize it so that it will work with any `M[_]` rather then with `Option` only. So I will try to write the `OptionalList` and post a question about it. Sounds like a plan :)

Comment: `ListT` is pretty neat—I strongly recommend taking a stab at an implementation. If you run into problems you know where to ask questions—

Answer (score 2):

The simplest modification I could think of is as below:

```
for{
    orderId <- getOrders.getOrElse(Nil)
    items <- getOrderItems(orderId)
} yield items
```

The for comprehension uses the first statement to determins the rest the types. For instance in the above the type `List[Int]` would be infered and this is different from `Option[List[Int]]`.

Comment: As you note, this doesn't match the spec.