# How to compose functions that return Option[Future] in Scala?

Tags: scala, future, monad-transformers

This is a follow-up to my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22296961/how-to-compose-functions-that-return-optionlist-in-scala)

Suppose there are a function `f1: A => Option[Future[B]]`, which calls a remote server asynchronously, and function `f2: B => Option[Future[C]]`, which in turn calls the server again. Now I wonder how to compose thesevfunctions `f1` and `f2` to make a new function `f3: A => Option[Future[C]]`.

If I followed the answer to the previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22296961/how-to-compose-functions-that-return-optionlist-in-scala) I would use something like `FutureT` similar to `ListT`

```
val f3 = {a:A =>
  (for {b <- FutureT(f1(a)); c <- FutureT(f2(b))}).underlying}
```

Does it make sense ? Should I write this `FutureT` by myself ?

Comment: Why do you want an optional future? Usually, a future option is what's desired. Specifically, the type of "a function that calls something asynchronously and might have a good answer" is definitely `Future[Option[_]]`.

Comment: `Option[Future[_]]` has a bit of "code smell" to it; if these are functions that are under your control, you probably want to return `Future[_]` in all cases and if "doing something" asynchronously is conditional, just use `Future.value(...)` in the non-async path to keep the return type consistent.

Comment: @RobStarling Suppose I call function `f`, which calls the server and _immediately_ fails (e.g. the server address was wrong). There is no point to return a future in this case. The function should either return None or throw an exception.

Comment: I have to agree with Rob's advice on this, despite your rejoinder. The point of always returning a Future is to avoid unnecessarily piling up types that make your life awkward. There's absolutely nothing wrong with returning a Future that fails immediately.

Comment: @Michael if the server fails immediately you can just returned a failed future. Plus, IMHO, a None is used to indicate the absence of value/result, not a failure.

Comment: Thank you all. I don't agree 100% with you but I will definitely reconsider using `Option[Future[A]]` return type.