# Example of Applicative composition in Scala

Tags: scala, scalaz, applicative

This is a followup to my old [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19880207/examples-of-applicative-functor-usage-in-scala):

I know that monads are not composable, i.e. if `M1[_]` and `M2[_]` are monads `M2[M1[_]]` is not necessarily a monad. For instance, `List[Int]` and `Option[Int]` are monads but `Option[List[Int]]` is not *automatically* a monad and therefore I need a `monad transformer` to use it as a monad (as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22296961/how-to-compose-functions-that-return-optionlist-in-scala))

I know that applicative functors are composable. I guess it means that if `A1[_]` and `A2[_]` are applicatives then `A2[A1[_]]` is *always* an applicative. Is it correct ?

Could you provide an example of such a composition when `A1` is `List` and `A2` is `Option` ? Could you give an example of other applicatives composed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added some examples to the scalaz source a while back which are relevant. I added examples of using composed Apply instances (Apply is Applicative without the point method):

https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/series/7.2.x/example/src/main/scala/scalaz/example/ApplyUsage.scala#L132-L147

but yes, for any `M1[_]` for which we have `Applicative[M1]` and `M2[_]` for which we have `Applicative[M2]`, `M1[M2[_]]` is applicative, and you can get the Applicative instance with `Applicative[M1] compose Applicative[M2]`