# How to define <*> for Option[List[_]] n Scala

Tags: scala, applicative

This is a followup to my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28850636/example-of-applicative-composition-in-scala) with an example found on the Internet.

Suppose I define a typeclass `Applicative` as follows:

```
trait Functor[T[_]]{
  def map[A,B](f:A=>B, ta:T[A]):T[B]
}

trait Applicative[T[_]] extends Functor[T] {
  def unit[A](a:A):T[A]
  def ap[A,B](tf:T[A=>B], ta:T[A]):T[B]
}
```

I can define an instance of `Applicative` for `List`

```
object AppList extends Applicative[List] {
  def map[A,B](f:A=>B, as:List[A]) = as.map(f)
  def unit[A](a: A) = List(a)
  def ap[A,B](fs:List[A=>B], as:List[A]) = for(f <- fs; a <- as) yield f(a)
}
```

For convenience I can define an `implicit conversion` to add a method `<*>` to `List[A=>B]`

```
implicit def toApplicative[A, B](fs: List[A=>B]) = new {
  def <*>(as: List[A]) = AppList.ap(fs, as)
}
```

Now I can do a cool thing !
zip two lists `List[String]` and apply `f2` to every pair in *applicative* style

```
val f2: (String, String) => String = {(first, last) => s"$first $last"}
val firsts = List("a", "b", "c")
val lasts  = List("x", "y", "z")

scala> AppList.unit(f2.curried) <*> firsts <*> lasts
res31: List[String] = List(a x, a y, a z, b x, b y, b z, c x, c y, c z)
```

So far, so good but now I have:

```
val firstsOpt = Some(firsts)
val lastsOpt  = Some(lasts)
```

I would like to zip `firsts` and `lasts`, apply `f2`, and get `Option[List[String]]` in *applicative* style. In other words I need `<*>` for `Option[List[_]]`. How can I do it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, you need an instance of applicative for `Option`:

```
implicit object AppOption extends Applicative[Option] {
  def map[A, B](f: A => B, o: Option[A]) = o.map(f)
  def unit[A](a: A): Option[A] = Some(a)
  def ap[A, B](of: Option[A => B], oa: Option[A]) = of match {
    case Some(f) => oa.map(f)
    case None => None
  }
}
```

Then you can also create an applicative instance for the composition of two applicatives (note, based on the [Haskell version](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.4.2.0/docs/src/Data-Functor-Compose.html#Compose)):

```
class AppComp[F[_], G[_]](fa: Applicative[F], ga: Applicative[G]) extends Applicative[({ type f[A] = F[G[A]]})#f] {
  def map[A, B](f: A => B, a: F[G[A]]): F[G[B]] = fa.map((g: G[A]) => ga.map(f, g), a)
  def unit[A](a: A) = fa.unit(ga.unit(a))
  def ap[A, B](f: F[G[A => B]], a: F[G[A]]): F[G[B]] = {
    val liftg: G[A => B] => (G[A] => G[B]) = gf => (gx => ga.ap(gf, gx))
    val ffg: F[G[A] => G[B]] = fa.map(liftg, f)
    fa.ap(ffg, a)
  }
}

implicit def toComp[F[_], G[_]](implicit fa: Applicative[F], ga: Applicative[G]) = new AppComp[F, G](fa, ga)
```

Finally you can now do:

```
val ola = toComp[Option, List]
ola.ap(ola.ap(ola.unit(f2.curried), firstsOpt), lastsOpt)
```

You could probably also remove some of the noise by generalising `<*>` to work for any applicative.

Comment: Great ! Thanks. Did you use `scalaz` to implement `AppComp` ? Can I find `AppComp` or something similar in `scalaz` ?

Comment: @Michael - I don't know scalaz but it looks like `compose` in [Applicative.scala](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/series/7.2.x/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Applicative.scala) does what you want.

Comment: Thank you. I will have a look at the `compose`.

Comment: Note that having multiple `Applicative[Option[List[?]]` instances in scope can lead to problems (including confusing or impossible type inference and more importantly breaking users' expectations). Going the Haskell route (which here would involve a wrapper with a new `Applicative` via an isomorphism) is probably better.