# How to fix implicit conversion to Applicative?

Tags: scala, scalaz, applicative

This is a follow-up to my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28875350/how-to-define-for-optionlist-n-scala)

I would like to generalize the implicit conversion `toApplicative`, which adds method `<*>` to any `M[A=>B]`, where `M` is `Applicative` (i.e. there is a typeclass instance `Applicative[M]`)

```
implicit def toApplicative[M[_], A, B](mf: M[A=>B])(implicit apm: Applicative[M]) = 
   new { def<*>(ma: M[A]) = apm.ap(ma)(mf) }
```

Unfortunately I have got an error:

```
   <console>:25: error: Parameter type in structural refinement 
            may not refer to an abstract type defined outside that refinement
```

How would you suggest implement such an implicit conversion ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The types `M` and `A` are referenced from your `def` so they need to be part of the thing you're returning. I can't see any way to do this completely with the structural refinement, so I think you have to define a parametrized class; how about defining an `implicit class` rather than the `implicit def`?

```
implicit class PimpedApplicative[M[_]: Applicative, A, B](mf: M[A => B]) {
  def <*>(ma: M[A]) = Applicative[M].ap(ma)(mf)
}
```